# how can I help my team be included in company social events?

Tags: socializing

I manage a small team of myself and 2 others. The other software engineering teams at my organization tend to all get along and interact with each other socially a lot, while my team members are excluded.

For example, an employee recently left the company and the other teams in my department all took them out to a farewell lunch. My team was not invited.

I'm a bit more of a introvert and less concerned that I personally was not invited, but I worry about my team members becoming demoralized since they were not included.

What can I do to help my team feel more included?

Comment: Is your team excluded or forgotten?

Comment: What @cdkMoose says is really important, there's a difference.

Comment: How much interaction is there between your team and the others?

Comment: @cdkMoose Good question. I'd say more forgotten than intentionally excluded.

Answer (score 6):

If there is a regular meeting of development team managers, that would be an excellent forum to have a discussion about events across teams.

If you don't already have such a meeting, you might consider trying to get one started.  This can help with communication across teams regarding technical, business and informal activities.

These meetings help keep all teams aware of the other teams and what is going on in other parts of the company and can reduce not being noticed or remembered.

Answer (score 1):

It's only 3 people. Why don't you and your team, or just you, invite one or two people from one of the other teams out to lunch every so often? Maybe you'll be remembered more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this counts as a full answer, but it's too much for a comment!

If your company makes use of email aliases, see if there is a "development" one and make sure you and your team members are on it.